# How populate and array whose rows were combinations and columns the different groups?(labview)

Tags: arrays, labview

I know the question is confusing so I´ll try to explain my problem. I am working in a labview project and one of the things I have to do is, after asking the user the number of variables and number of different values for each one of them, create an array with all de combinations.

Lets supose we have 3 different variables , for example:
var1, var2, var3

and the number of diffent values for each of them is:

```
var1 -> 0, 1, 2
var2 -> 11, 22
var3 -> 55, 66, 77, 88
```

So, the resulting array  should be like this:

```
0 11 55
0 11 66
0 11 77
0 22 55
0 22 66
...
```

this way until 3 x 2 x 4 = 24 rows

Taking into account that the number of variables and values of each one usually will be different how can I populate this array?

I need how to do it with labview.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "Cartesian Product".

You can use gmath/Discrete Math.llb/Cartesian Product of Lists.vi to accomplish this:

[image: labview code]

This gives the intended result:

[image: result]

The way it works is you feed the Cartesian Product VI a 1D array detailing the size of several arrays you want to get the Cartesian product of, and it generates the corresponding indices you need to index the respective arrays to create the Cartesian product.

All you need to do is build a 2D array of (1D array of row vectors) that contains all the information you want to compute the Cartesian product of, and a 1D array that shows the size of each individual row vector. In LabVIEW, when you build an array of 1D arrays, the number of columns becomes max(len(row_vector_i)), so to preserve this length information for automatic cross product, the best way is to simply build a 1D array of clusters, where each cluster has an individual 1D array, or row vector. This preserves the size information.

Here's what that looks like:

[image: cluster auto]

I saved all of this into a project that should be completely compatible with LV8.6, [found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hs2vnyrye33vl0/Cartesian%20Product%20Folder.zip?dl=0)

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, I`ll try it. The only one problem is that the number of variables not always is 3 but also may be 1,2,4,5.... The only solution I find is create a condictional structure with 5 or 6 "if", from 2 to 6 or 7 vars, and into each "if" condition place the solution you have suggested for 3 variables. Thanks so much.

Comment: I've had a big problem, my LV version is 8.6 and doesn´t have Cartesian Product.

Comment: I created the example and added it to the main post. The cartesian product VI takes variable length lists into account, using it's "number of elements in each list" array input.

Comment: I have  just read your last answer right now. I`ll try it because it looks so smart. I have another related question; knowing a combination a values how can I know the row in "Cartesian Product  of Row vectors"??

Comment: Pablo, I think the best way would be to just do a 2D array search (look up 2D array search LabVIEW, you'll find loads of examples) on the end result set. I'm sure there's a combinatorial answer that gives a closed form in terms of the indices and list sizes, but the array search is probably the most straight forward approach.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and samples way is to use 3 for loops inside each other.

So the smallest for loop will iterate var3,

medium for loop will iterate var2 and

large for loop will iterate var1.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a python implementation, would help if you can specify the language you are implementing in.

```
def array_3d(var1,var2,var3):
  a = []
  for i in range(len(var1)):
    for j in range(len(var2)):
      for k in range(len(var3)):
        a.append([var1[i],var2[j],var3[k]])
  print a


array_3d([1,2,3],[10,20,30],[300,400,500,600])
```